# search based on contents of lines above and below a search term

Tags: regex, grep, notepad++

So I have a log file that has text like this.. many variations of it though:

> m=audio 16468 RTP/AVP 0 8 9 18 120 102 104 103 101
>  a=rtpmap:0
>   pcmu/8000
>  a=rtpmap:8 pcma/8000
>  a=rtpmap:9 g722/8000
>   a=rtpmap:18 g729/8000
>  a=fmtp:18 annexb=yes
>  a=rtpmap:120
>   opus/48000/2
>  a=rtpmap:102 iLBC/8000
>  a=rtpmap:104
>   iSAC/32000
>  a=rtpmap:103 iSAC/16000
>  a=rtpmap:101
>   telephone-event/8000
>  a=fmtp:101 0-15

and I want to search using something.. notepad++.. grep.. whatever might work for this really.

I need to find only the blocks that have this line..

> a=rtpmap:18 g729/8000

But don't have this line within 4 or 5 lines above or below it:

> a=rtpmap:0 pcmu/8000

Any ideas on how I would go about doing this?  I have found posts on how to search for something and then also print out the lines above/below it.. but not have to not show it if one of the lines above and below contain x.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: `grep 'a=rtpmap:18 g729/8000' file`

Comment: @poul-bak I have not tried anything as I don't know how to do what i'm wanting to do.  I can search and grep for a single line of text without issue, I just don't know how to filter the results based off of text in lines above/below the search term.

Comment: @Cyrus Wouldn't that just return all the lines with that term regardless of the contents of the above/below lines?  That is not what I am looking to do.

Comment: What are the criteria to select `a=rtpmap:18 g729/8000` but not `a=rtpmap:0 pcmu/8000`? Is the search string exactly `a=rtpmap:18 g729/8000` or are there some possible variation? Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52485577/edit) and add more sample lines an expected result.

Comment: What is a "block"?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this on notepad++ for example: `m=audio.*\r?\n(?!(?:^a=.*\r?\n)*^a=rtpmap:0 pcmu/8000)(?:^a=.*\r?\n)*^a=rtpmap:18 g729/8000\r?\n(?:^a=.*\r?\n)*`

That will find `m=audio` blocks, that must be followed by `a=` lines.

It will select the whole block as long as it finds `a=rtpmap:18 g729/8000` and there is no `a=rtpmap:0 pcmu/8000` on the same block (regarthless of the *distance* between them)

Note: For notepad++, do **not** use the '. matches newline'

See Demo **[here](https://regex101.com/r/PI4I8u/1/)**.

Comment: This works perfectly in notepad++ through the audio line will not always be the same after the word audio.  There are innumerable possibilities of what the rest of the line would look like as its a combination of port number and other possible values.  From the provided search string it looks to be looking for that line explicitly and there were no other results besides the file used to create the above samples.  I will update the question with better examples and criteria as Toto requested.